# how the exec() function maintain the memory spaces?

Tags: c, exec, fork

I read the exec() function in c. they said when the exec() functions are called in a child process . that will replace the new program.

i have a doubt on that, if i run the process, take it take 10 MB(for example) of memory.so when i create a child process, that also having a same memory space.

in child process i call the exec() function, it will take another executable file. consider that need 30MB memory. then how that process will work.. please explain with example?

in a another program i just declare the array as

```
  array[100000]={5};
```

and i run that compile that program. and in another program i just call the fork() and exec() function. but it properly work.

Comment: When you `fork` a new child process, it's an exact copy of the parent process. However, some data (like the executable code segments) may be shared. However, when you call `exec` all traces of the current process are lost and its memory unmapped/free'd, and the data of the new process will be properly allocated (so if the new program have a large static array it will be allocated by the loader as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory mappings are replaced when you call any of the exec*() functions.

It doesn't matter how much memory the child process uses after fork() as exec*() will cause the existing memory mappings of the process to be destroyed and new memory to be allocated/mapped for the new executable.

See also the official [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) on what exec() does